# Need help figuring how to make script to convert number to variable and sorting the array and displaying the results

Tags: javascript

having trouble figuring how to make script to convert number to variable and sorting the array and displaying the results. Need it to convert the numbers the user inputs into variables. Also, would want to sort the array results in descending order.

Here is my code:

```js
var x = 0;
var z = 0;
var array = Array();

function hellarray() {
    array[x] = document.getElementById("mad").value;
    alert(array[x] + " was added to array");
    x++;
    
    document.getElementById("mad").value = "";
    
    var e = "<hr/>";
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        e += "Element " + y + " = " + array[y] + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = e;
}


function diearray() {
    array[z] = document.getElementById("mad").value;
    points.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
    document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = array[z];
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mad">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="hellarray();">
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Descending" onclick="diearray();">
<p id="sadness"></p>
```

Comment: why not use a single function to get the value of the input and then increment or decrement from there? Capture the event in your function like: ```function handler(event){}``` and inside, you can figure out who called it with ```e.target.id```. You can get also the value with ```e.target.value```

Comment: Also, you should declare the array at the top with a better name like: ```var userInputs = [];```

Answer (score -1):

Right now you are adding elements to the DOM, and then you are trying to sort these DOM-elements. It's usually a good ide to keep data and the actual view separate.

I would suggest that you first only add elements to your array and sort this array. Then you have a separate function thats only responsible for rendering this array to your users.

I have also renamed some functions and variables to more meaningfull names than `hellarray`, `array` and `e`. It's always a good ide to give your variables names that will make sense to you in the future!

```js
let listItems = [];

function addToList(event) {
    const inputField = document.getElementById("mad");
    const inputValue = Number(inputField.value);
    
    // You should do a check that inputValue is actually a number here
    
    // Add element to our list
    listItems.push(inputValue)

    // From what I understand you want to sort the list imediately
    listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a
    });
    
    // Render the list for the user
    renderList()
    
    // Clear inputfield
    inputField.value = ""
}

function renderList() {
    var domList = "";

    for (let y = 0; y < listItems.length; y++) {
        domList += "Element " + y + " = " + listItems[y] + "<br/>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("sadness").innerHTML = domList;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mad">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="addToList();">
<hr/>
<p id="sadness"></p>
```